# Schema validation component is mule esb

Tags: validation, xsd, mule, mule-component

I'm using schema validation component for xml validation.

In my scenario xml comes from JMS queue and need to place in other JMS queue in between I need to validate incoming xml whether it is proper or not by XSD Schema.

but when I put logger after Schema Validation component it is not logging( logging as[#document: null]) xml even input xml is as per XSD Schema.

```
<mulexml:schema-validation-filter name="Schema_Validation" schemaLocations="C:\src\test\resources\Orders.xsd" returnResult="true" doc:name="Schema Validation" />
<logger message="content is #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Please suggest me on this., Thanks...,

Comment: Given your config xml, if your xml is not valid, it will stop processing which explains it does not log. But if is indeed valid, the log should have executed.

Comment: Hi Tyrone,
I have generated input xml from XSD Schema itself so my input xml is proper moreover when I give improper XML as input it is throwing error message i.e logger is not executed. when ever I give proper XML only flow is moving forward and logging  :   [#document: null].

Comment: Do as Franck said so your payload remains the same before filter. What are you are getting is already a DOM class that's why [#document: null]. If you want to process filtered (invalid XML), there's a config for it, mix of global schema filter and message filter.

Comment: Have u tried  <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer /> right after validation filter and before logger ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get a stacktrace? Can you set a logger directly after the JMS endpoint and validate whether it is a correct message or not? Is it a nested schema?

Answer (score 0):

> In order to allow a valid XML to pass the filter you need to set the
>   returnResult to false in your schema-validation-filter. This way the
>   payload of the message that is passed onwards to the next element in
>   your flow will retain the XML content.